# reset variables after browser resized using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a jquery function that can be called both on ready and when the browser window is resized.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

function setWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var boxWidth = $('#addbox').width();
    var paddingWidth = (windowWidth - boxWidth) / 2;
};

$(setWidth);

$(window).resize(setWidth);

$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft:$(this.hash).offset().left-paddingWidth}, 750);
});
```

});

But that code doesn't seem to be working, firebug says that paddingWidth isn't defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what scope are you trying to access `paddingWidth`? The way that you've declared it, it's only scoped within the function `setWidth`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include all the code. Fixing that so you can see the entire scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables have the scope in which they were defined (using `var`).  In your case, this means that they are only defined within `setWidth`, and are re-initialised on each execution of that method.

You should move them into a containing scope so that functions in descendant scopes have access to their values.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var windowWidth, boxWidth, paddingWidth; // declare variables in this scope

    function setWidth() {
        windowWidth = $(window).width(); // set variables in this scope
        boxWidth = $('#addbox').width();
        paddingWidth = (windowWidth - boxWidth) / 2;
    };

    setWidth(); // just call the function

    $(window).resize(setWidth);

    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left - paddingWidth
        }, 750);
    });
});
```

Note that `$(setWidth)` is an odd call, and a relatively expensive one.  It says "call `setWidth` when the document is ready".  Since you are in a `jQuery(document).ready` handler, you can be sure that that is true.  You can just execute the function with `setWidth()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var paddingWidth = 0;

function setWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var boxWidth = $('#addbox').width();
    paddingWidth = (windowWidth - boxWidth) / 2;
};

$(setWidth);

$(window).resize(setWidth);

$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft:$(this.hash).offset().left-paddingWidth}, 750);
});
```