# Window Resize: Applying a Custom Function

Tags: jquery, resize

I have developed a responsive site and am trying to set apply a variable that is set on window resize  if  a screen resolution that is lower than 1500px

Here is my resize script. I am working on just one button to start with:

http://thosedigitalthoughts.com/deppro2/js/detect.js

So if the screen is lower than 1500px the variable is 61% and if the screen is higher then the variable is 50.6666%

I have tried this on one button  in main menu but I get a div that slides in and out multiple times.

http://thosedigitalthoughts.com/deppro2/

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Media queries in CSS if you want to animate on screen size change. [Media Queries Usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Hi Thanks for that but I am using jquery to slide panels in from right of screen. There is a variable within my function that needs to be updated on resize event. Updated link is here:

http://thosedigitalthoughts.com/deppro3/

Comment: Found an answer here finally...was all about variable scope...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600418/reset-variables-after-browser-resized-using-jquery